# How to add new summernote toolbar without updating all pages?

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, summernote

I have summernote toolbar in several pages, I have specified toolbars in all pages, so if i need to add new toolbar I want to update all pages , how can i add toolbar in summernote.js so that i dont want to update all pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should init several text editors. For example on one page it will be something like:

```
$('#page1Element').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    ['style', ['style]],
    ['color', ['color']]
  ]
});
```

and for another page:

```
$('#page2Element').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    ['style', ['style]],
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture']]
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay Alex but you are asking me to update all pages , but i dont want to update all pages , i just need to add the toolbar in summernote.js file so i can access the toolbar in all pages. (i am not using the default toolbars , so i cant specify it in summernote.js default toolbar method )